# Why does the limit $ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0+}\int_{\varepsilon}^M \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}\ dx$ exist for smooth $\varphi$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $D(\Bbb{R}):=C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ and 
$$
p.v.(1/x)(\varphi):=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\ dx. 
$$
for $\varphi\in D(\Bbb{R})$. I'm trying to understand why this limit exists.

---

Here is what I tried so far. 
Given a test function $\varphi\in D(\Bbb{R})$, there exists $M>1>0$ such that for small $\varepsilon>0$, 
$$
\int_{\varepsilon<|x|}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\ dx=\int_{\varepsilon<|x|<M}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\ dx
=\int_{\varepsilon<|x|<M}\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}\ dx
$$
since
$$
\int_{\varepsilon<|x|<M}\frac{\varphi(0)}{x}\ dx=0
$$
by symmetry. This integral exists since the continuous function
$$
\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}
$$
has compact support in $\{x:\varepsilon<|x|<M\}$. Now things boil down to showing that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0+}\int_{\varepsilon}^M
\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}\ dx$$
exists. 
If one define 
$$
f(x)=\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x},\quad x\not=0
$$
and $f(0):=\varphi'(0)$. Then f(x) is continuous on $[0,M]$ and thus 
$$
\int_0^M f(x)\ dx
$$
exists. I don't know how to convince myself that 
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0+}\int_{\varepsilon}^M
\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}\ dx
=\int_0^M f(x)\ dx.
$$

Comment: Use the fact that $\phi$ is a test function to bound $\frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)}{x}$ uniformly near 0.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\varphi(x) - \varphi(0)}{x} = \varphi'(0)$$ whenever $\varphi$ is differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty much there. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,M]$, it follows that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_\varepsilon^Mf(x)\, dx=\int_0^Mf(x)\, dx$.

EDIT: $f$ here is defined as you originally did before you edited the question:
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}
\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}x&\text{if }x>0,\\
\varphi'(0)&\text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$